# Fitness function using php in genetic algorithm

Tags: php, genetic-algorithm

I have some problem about GA for selecting the best employee positions.

This is the case:

I have 4 employees selected (`E1`,`E2`,`E3`,`E4`) and their in 3 population :

```
* Random array ( Population I )= (
    [0] = E1 => 200,
    [1] = E2 => 155,
    [2] = E3 => 130, 
    [3] = E4 => 98 
)

* Random array ( Population II )= (
    [0] = E2 => 155,
    [1] = E3 => 130,
    [2] = E1 => 200, 
    [3] = E4 => 98 
)

* Random array ( Population III )= (
    [0] = E4 => 98,
    [1] = E1 => 200,
    [2] = E3 => 130, 
    [3] = E2 => 155 
)
```

Then, I want to input that score into this function :

```
f =  ( N * score[0] ) + ( (N-1) * score[1] ) + score[2] + score[3] / N)
```

NB : `N` is count of employees selected.

Example fitness function (Manual Calculations):

```
Population I : (4*200) + ((4-1)*155) + 130 + 98 / 4 = 373,25

Population II : (4*155) + ((4-1)*130) + 200 + 98 / 4 = 327

Population III : (4*98) + ((4-1)*200) + 130 + 155 / 4 = 319,25
```

So how do I implement the manual calculations using PHP code ?

Can someone help me? I'm trying this for a week now but still no luck :(

Comment: `"i was tried 1 week but still not solved"`, mind showing us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's an example implementation](https://eval.in/174307) of your formula. There are two glaring problems with your question however, so let's go through those first:

1. How on earth are your arrays actually structured? Your examples aren't very clear - arrays only have one key and one value. In my example I've interpreted your examples as literal values, and I've split them into the numbers in the function. Adjust to suit.
2. How do you want this formula to scale up depending on how many employees are selected? My implementation has the first and second entries hard coded, then it would scale automatically after that by simply adding the "population" on for each value after the first two.
3. A bonus question/problem: your formula has a bracket at the end, which from a glance, followed by a glance over the formula from left to right seems to imply that the second half of your formula is added and divided by N, which is incorrect because your expected output values occur when the entire result is divided by N.

Anyway, here's an implentation:

```
function doMyCalculation($selections) {
    // Get number of selected employees
    $num_selected = count($selections);

    // Break up the format of your array - what is it supposed to be?
    array_walk($selections, function(&$employee) {
        list($emp, $val) = explode('=>', $employee);
        $employee = (int) $val;
    });

    // Initialize variable
    $return = 0;
    // Loop through all "employees"
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_selected; $i++) {
        // For the first two, we're going to use N as a multiplier
        if($i < 2) 
             // Use [N - current] as the multiplier (only twice)
            $return += ($num_selected - $i) * $selections[$i];
        else
            // Otherwise, just add it normally
            $return += $selections[$i];
    }

    // Divide the whole lot by N
    $return /= $num_selected;

    return $return;
}

echo doMyCalculation($arr1); // 373.25
echo doMyCalculation($arr2); // 327
echo doMyCalculation($arr3); // 319.25
```

You should think about the points above to work out how you're going to scale this if you select more than four or less than four employees etc. Hard to provide an accurate answer without that knowledge.